# Flutter Taking too long to execute

Tags: flutter

I just started using flutter and I headed straight to their website and downloaded the latest version (2.5.3 for windows) for my windows 10 machine . I unzipped the zip file and added flutter to my environment path variables. If I run flutter in any command prompt whether cmd or windows power shell everything works fine, but if I try to run any flutter command , it gives this line which takes almost forever to execute even if I have a strong internet connection.

```
   **D:\Flutter\FlutterProjects>flutter create first_app
   Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...**
```

Comment: It's takes more time, the first time you run it.  happened to me too

Comment: @david okoroafor like how much time , 1hour? . Please i want to know because I've being sitting here for long now and nothing is happening

Comment: nah. It might be network issue try running it with a VPN.

Comment: I'm thinking of downgrading to a lower version to see if it works

Comment: it isn't about the version.

Comment: Then what is it then? Is there a bug ?

Comment: After a very long time of research on github, I found out that it was the network I'm using that caused the download to waste too much time. For Nigerian developers especially, use MTN to download , do not use GLO because It cannot access the website pub.dev when running the command. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I tried to: downgrade/upgrade SDK, change SDK path, and reinstall the OS, but  nothing happens
then **I tried to connect to a VPN** and it worked fine